# How to get list from repeater table to Server side in Asp.net Webform

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

First, i add two rows in repeater on page load.than second step i append other rows using jquery on button click. no i have a aspx button control and i want a list of tbody on server side but i get only two rows. my requirements is that i want to get all rows on server side.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" id="txtname" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" value="" />
            <br />
            <input type="text" id="txtcountry" placeholder="Enter Country" name="country" value="" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="name" value="Add" id="btnAdd" />
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>

    <form runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"/>
        <asp:Repeater ID="tbDetail" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table id="tbDetails">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Country</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="name" value='<%#Eval("Name")%>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="name" value='<%#Eval("Country")%>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
            debugger
            var txtname = $("#txtname").val();
            var txtcountry = $("#txtcountry").val();


            $('#tbDetails tbody').append("<tr>"
            + "<td><input type='text' name='name' value='" + txtname + "' /></td>"
            + "<td><input type='text' name='name' value='" + txtcountry + "' /></td></tr>"
            );
        })
    });
</script>
```

aspx.cs page btnSubmit_Click on this event i get only two rows

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                List<Data> li = new List<Data>
             {
                 new Data { Name = "Umar", Country = "Pakistan" },
                 new Data { Name = "Ali", Country = "Pakistan" }
             };

                tbDetail.DataSource = li;
                tbDetail.DataBind();
            }
        }
        private class Data
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Country { get; set; }
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var count = tbDetail.Items.Count;

        }
```

Comment: whatever you are doing on client side has no effect on the server side control.

Comment: but my requirements is that

Comment: You could post the name and country back to the server first and update the table with the new row.